# How to ignore lines for code coverage in Jest

Tags: code-coverage, jestjs, istanbul

In Jest, is there any way to ignore code for test coverage?
I tried using

```js
/* istanbul ignore next */
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 56):

It works.

```js
(function(global) {
    var defineAsGlobal = true;
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    if(typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = lib;
        defineAsGlobal = false;
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    if(typeof modules === 'object' && typeof modules.define === 'function') {
        modules.define('lib', function(provide) {
            provide(lib);
        });
        defineAsGlobal = false;
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    if(typeof define === 'function') {
        define(function(require, exports, module) {
            module.exports = lib;
        });
        defineAsGlobal = false;
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    defineAsGlobal && (global.lib = lib);
})(this);
```

Sample project https://github.com/ilyar/sandbox/tree/master/jest

Comment: does not work for me. im using react scripts v2.1.5 with jest v23.6.0

Answer (score 35):

Update for anyone that finds this at a later date.

```js
/* istanbul ignore next */
```

Will work but as read from The Jest Official Documentation:

> ***coveragePathIgnorePatterns seems to not have any effect.***
>
> Make sure you are not using the **babel-plugin-istanbul** plugin. Jest
> wraps Istanbul, and therefore also tells Istanbul what files to
> instrument with coverage collection. When using babel-plugin-istanbul,
> every file that is processed by Babel will have coverage collection
> code, hence it is not being ignored by coveragePathIgnorePatterns.

The documentation can be found here: [Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#coveragepathignorepatterns-seems-to-not-have-any-effect)

So in order to fix this issue uninstall babel-plugin-istanbul:

> If it is a library based only on javascript, than you can just run `npm uninstall --save babel-plugin-istanbul` or `npm uninstall --save-dev babel-plugin-istanbul`
> If you've installed a library with native content that requires linking, and you've linked it with rnpm then you can do: `rnpm unlink package_name` then follow step 1 - Aakash Sigdel

This quote was from Aakash Sigdel found here: [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38618379/1936663)

Comment: If using create react app, which installs this plugin for you instead try using collectCoverageFrom and ! to negate a path: "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",

Comment: This doesn't work for me even after uninstalling `babel-plugin-istanbul`, the lines are shown in the coverage (using TS).

Comment: In my case, I had   coverageProvider: 'v8', and it was causing this to break. doing:
  coverageProvider: 'babel',
fixed it and the pragma works great.

Answer (score 14):

Just for anyone finding this who uses the `v8` provider:
[the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean) now state how to ignore lines with different providers, and link to more details. But basically either `/* c8 ignore next */` or `/* c8 ignore start */` + `/*c8 ignore end */` should work well with the `v8` provider.

Example:

```js
/* c8 ignore next */
if (process.env.DEBUG) console.log('debug');

/* c8 ignore start */
switch (process.env.DEBUG) {
case '1':
  console.log('some verbosity');
  break;
case '2':
  console.log('a lot of verbosity');
  break;
}
/* c8 ignore end */
```

Answer (score 12):

Found a workaround (spaces before and after the comment seem to be necessary):

```js
class Foo {
  bar /* istanbul ignore next */ () {
    return 'biu~';
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I have to place the comment right in front of the function to be ignored, instead of above it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had coverageProvider: 'v8', and it was causing this to break. doing: coverageProvider: 'babel', fixed it and the pragma works great.

Answer (score 0):

According to [a babel issue thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10432) Istambul appears to have a bug where it assumes the preceding line of code is terminated with a semi-colon...

```js
constructor(message: string) {
  // TODO: how do I get Jest code coverage for "super(message)?
  // /* istanbul ignore next */ assumes the preceding line of code is terminated with a ;
    DEBUG: console.log();
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    super(message);
}
```