# React native android APK release build failed

Tags: android, react-native

I have tried to build release build APK for my project. The project is perfectly working in the simulator. The problem is, showing some errors. I cannot trace what is the error about. Please check the below screenshot for errors.

[image: Build Error]

Code used for APK generation: **cd android && gradlew assembleRelease**

Please check the below Gradle properties, if anything is wrong.

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raottsworld"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        innerTest {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')

    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    implementation project(":react-native-image-zoom")
    implementation project(":react-native-photo-view")
    implementation project(":react-native-vector-icons")
    implementation project(":react-native-video")
    implementation project(":react-native-maps")
    implementation project(":RNPermissionsModule")
    implementation (project(":react-native-fcm")) {
        exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
    }
    implementation (project(":react-native-maps")) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-base"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-maps"
    }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1") {
        force = true;
    }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1") {
        force = true;
    }
    implementation project(":react-native-image-picker")
    implementation project(":react-native-camera")
    implementation project(":react-native-fcm")
    implementation project(":react-native-svg")
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1') {
        force = true;
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

`Versions Used`

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

I am stuck in the above error, really need help to fix the error.

Comment: Issue is with the your support library version. And other thing is react-native-android-permissions is an archived plugin, use react-native-community/react-native-permissions instead of react-native-android-permissions, this might resole your issue

Comment: @EL173 `npm install --save react-native-permissions`, this one. right?

Comment: yes before that remove your current react-native-android-permissions  module and do the relevant changes in your code, basically change the usage of react-native-android-permissions

Comment: @EL173 ok. let me try.

Comment: @EL173 I have added the new react-native-permissions module. Now the error show is, `error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of RNPermissionsPackage
import com.reactnativecommunity.rnpermissions.RNPermissionsPackage;`

Comment: Check your previous module link is already there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613790/how-to-delete-installed-library-form-react-native-project